# Website URL for subpages not showing up after domain forwarding

Tags: domains, redirects, wordpress, amazon-ec2

I have a wordpress site setup on an amazon ec2 server. I created an elastic ip, forwarded my domain name (registered with namecheap) to that ip, and setup everything to properly work through aws's route 53.

The domain name, say www.example.com redirects correctly to the home page of my WordPress site, but when I navigate to a specific page on the site the URL does not change correctly to say example.com/page.html, but remains the same (example.com). This does not happen if I directly go to the ec2 elastic ip address, only when using the domain name redirect.

Am I doing something wrong here? How can I get the correct URL to appear through the domain name?

Comment: "Forwarding with masking" implements a frameset that uses HTML frames.   It creates a full page frame that directs the browser to fill in another website (in this case your IP address host) in the frame.   Framed masked redirects do not typically work well because search engines see right through them and URLs don't change as the user navigates.   Michael's answer tells you the correct way to set things up.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to "forward" your domain name.  That's what's causing this behavior.

You need to create a DNS `A` record for the hostname that you want to point to the elastic IP.

https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/434/2237/how-do-i-set-up-host-records-for-a-domain